# Evaluating RNZoomVideoSDKSession.getSessionName Error on Zoom Video SDK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk, zoom-sdk

After I @zoom/react-native-videosdk this dependency, the error is shown below. So to solve this error I changed the versions of dependencies. But not be solved. Please give me a suitable solution for this.

[image]

Used Technologies (Expo, React Native, Zoom Video SDK)